# Is there an Intern equivalent to TestNG/Java object.properties?

Tags: intern

Using Intern, can an element list (or object repository) be built and referenced from the tests using unique names instead of finding them every time, like the object.properties used in TestNG/Java?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: You can certainly retain references to an element across an entire test (or even across suites), but it is generally not a good idea. Are you looking for something like this? `var elements = {}; ... .findById('myElem').then(function (elem) { elements.myElem = elem; })`

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I'd rather not have to change a reference to an element 20 times if the xpath changes slightly.  Across a test, I can see that it would be ok.  Across suites, there should be no need.  Thanks!